# how to set the distance of length size each value in the X axis become same using R studio?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to set the length size of X-axis become the same in each chromosome.
For example:
the distance of length size from 0 to 5, 5 to 10, 10 to 15 etc in 2L chromosome and 2R chromosome become same.
does anyone know what is the package or script in R studio to do that?

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: What are you using to make the plots? So your goal is for these 2 plots to be different sizes so that their scales can match?

Comment: I made this from ggplot. Yes, I would like to make these 2 plots have the same length size between the x value in x axis like I explained above

Comment: Do you want both plots to have the same x-axis (so both go out to 25 MBp) and the same size/scale, but some empty space on the right of the bottom plot? Or do you want the scale of the plots to be the same, but the bottom plot will be shorter (less width) without the white space to the right?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.